# Grass Hair Particles not lighted correctly

Tags: particles, normals, lighting

so I've been working on a scene using hair particles instancing grass meshes. Now that I tried to set the lighting up using sun(s), the grass is not illuminated correctly. In fact, the side facing the sun is dark, while the other side is lighted, so the whole process is reverse. Here are some screenshots of which I hope that they will make it more understandable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnPfG.jpg

This occurs with any lighting source so I'm sure that the grass is the problem. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

edit: I would like to bump this as I could find no solution, neither on Stack Exchange nor anywhere else. Has anyone got an idea for the causes of this problem? The normals are alright.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: If you say reverse, meaning the grass is lightened up on the opposite of where the light is, flipping the normals of the grass should do the trick.

Comment: @Xylvier No, that did unfortunately not work. I optimized all the normals after your reply and it did nothing... I have no clue what it could be.

Comment: @Xylvier And the weird thing is that they are even casting their shadows in the right direction.